# Using Structured array in Numpy along with Numpy.where()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The data is imported from a text file which has column names in the first line and values in the subsequent lines, something like this :

```
Name|Age 
 tom|23
jack|13
```

I have a structured array that I created with the following statement.

```
types = ['U25','i']
data = np.genfromtxt(fname, dtype=types, delimiter=',',names=True)
```

The name of the second column is "age". I would like only the records where age is greater than 20. How do I go about this using Numpy.where()?

Comment: Focus on writing a boolean comparison; `where` is just a way of finding the `True` elements of an array.  Look at `data['age']`.  And `data['age']>20`.  If that boolean looks right, then `np.where(data['age']>20)`.  Again, look at before using it else where.